# How does a Quadratic approximation hug the original graph?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am watching a Khan Academy [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=szHMvVXxp-g&list=PLSQl0a2vh4HC5feHa6Rc5c0wbRTx56nF7&index=80) on quadratic approximations. They initially explained linear approximations, which I understood quite well. For instance, if one needs use $L = a + bx + cy$ to approximate a function $f$ then, in the equation of $L$, $b =\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial x}$. The same happened with $c$ except that it dealt with $y$ instead of $x$. Basically we want the slope of $L$ and $f$ to be equal at a point in the $x$ and $y$ directions

However, I don't understand what the speaker is doing with $Q = a + bx + cy + dx^2 + exy + fy^2$. For instance what does a double derivative even represent here? Does it represent the slope too? Why would it ensure that the curved surface (in blue) hugs the graph?
[image]

Comment: Before jumping both to two inputs and from linear to quadratic at the same time, do you already understand quadratic approximations for single-input functions?

Comment: The presenter claimed that this technique works for an arbitrary number of inputs. Therefore, I'll probably understand it for single-input functions, too, once my doubts are resolved.

Comment: The slope is not a double derivative, it is a single derivative. The double derivative is more related to the convexity or curvature at a point. I would agree with the advice to stick to a single variable First.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Could you maybe then explain it in terms of a single variable?

Comment: No time to watch the video sorry. You are going to have to put what you do not understand into a question.

Comment: The first derivative tells you the slope: the ratio of how fast the value of the function changes with respect to a change in the input. The second derivative is the first derivative that slope: it tells you how fast the *slope* of the function is changing with a change of the input. Think of a circle. The slope at some point is the slope of the tangent line. As you move the point around the circle, this slope changes, and second derivative tells you how fast. It is related to curvature, but how closely depends on which variables are your input.

Comment: Just like a linear approximation finds the plane (linear surface) that best approximates the surface around a point, the quadratic approximation finds the quadratic surface that best approximates the surface around a point. Just as with the linear approximation, near the point, it is good, but farther from the point it becomes bad, but it does so more slowly than the linear approximation. It will match not only the slope at the point in each direction, but also how the slope is changing in each direction.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I understand now. Thank you so much.